# How can I modify the core field "link" widget?

Tags: 8, forms

I need to alter the "Embed Link" form provided by Drupal 8 in the node AddForm. Namely I need to add a select list form item to specify the "type" of the  [image: embed link.]

For this I am trying to implement a hook_form_alter()

```
  if(isset($form['field_link_embed'])){
   $form['field_link_embed']['widget']['format'] = [
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#title' =>t("Link format"),
    '#options' => [
        'open' => t("option1"),
        'html' => t("option2"),
    ]
  ];
```

But I guess this is not the right chain how to access the form  $form['field_link_embed']['widget']['format'], could you please help me?

Comment: Are you trying to specify format for the `Link Text` or are you trying to make the `Link Text` a select box ?

Comment: I am trying to extend it with select box. So to say to add one more field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is quick and dirty `hook_form_alter` implementation that does this

Add this to your `THEMENAME.theme` or your `MODULENAME.module`

```
function THEMENAME_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == "node_article_edit_form" || $form_id == "node_article_form") {
    $link_count = intval($form["field_link_embed"]["widget"]["#max_delta"]);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $link_count; $i++) {
      if (isset($form["field_link"]["widget"][$i]["format"])) {
        continue;
      }
      $form["field_link"]["widget"][$i]["format"] = [
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#title' => t("Link format"),
        '#options' => [
          'open' => t("option1"),
          'html' => t("option2"),
        ],
      ];
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** you have to modify `node_article_form` and `node_article_edit_form` and perhaps `field_link_embed` to match your setup.

Perhaps for more involved implementation you should create a dedicated `field_formatter` using `web/core/modules/link/src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter/LinkFormatter.php` as a starting point.

Comment: Will it create a column in database?

Comment: Nope that is why I said its a quick and dirty solution, the use case of the above solution is ruther limited, and you actually never mentioned in your description that this is a requirement.

Comment: Sure, it is. I am sorry. Do I need to open a new question for it?

Comment: yeah I suppose this is the best way, as this is probably a complete question/answer already